# What is the difference between deploying models in MLflow and Sagemaker?

Tags: rest, deployment, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint, mlflow

I could do
`mlflow model serve -m <RUN_ID> --p 1234 --no-conda`

and

`mlflow sagemaker run-local -m <MODEL_PATH> -p 1234`

Are they not the same anyway as both can do model serving so what's the hassle deploying it to Sagemaker?

I'm a beginner at this so if anyone can help me out with my understanding that will be great. Thank you so much in advance!